# Vuetify v-select disable/remove dropdown

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-select

I would like a vuetify control where user can see and delete chips but not add any more chips.
The `<v-select>` component matches 99% of the requirements, except it has dropdown. How can I remove the dropdown from v-select (or achieve the goal with other componet)?

```
<v-select :label="Tags"
            v-model="tags"
            :items="tags"
            multiple chips deletable-chips
            hide-selected disable-lookup>
    <template slot="no-data">
        <div></div>
    </template>
</v-select>
```

I have tried setting `v-model == items` with `hide-selected`. However contrary to `v-combobox` there no `hide-no-data` prop on `v-select` so it still displays dropdown with "No data available" . While adding `no-data` slot with empty template hides the text but not the dropdown.  
Using `v-combobox` instead does not seem to be an option because the search/input field on v-combobox cannot be disabled neither. There is a prop `disable-lookup` on both components but it does not seem to do anything, certainly not disabling lookup. There is `readonly` prop on v-combobox that disables search input but it is not compatible with `deletable-chips`.

Comment: Update: in the end, rewriting `v-combobox` was easier: while it is no longer possible use `chips`, it is possible to implement own chips by overriding the `v-selection` slot.